# Finding the normalizer of a group

Tags: group-theory

Compute $N_{S_5}(\{(\begin{smallmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3
  \end{smallmatrix})\}).$ This is essentially asking for all of the permutations in $S_5$ that commute with $(\begin{smallmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3
  \end{smallmatrix})$, so far I only know that the identity and itself commute with it. Is there a trick to compute these permutations faster, and not bruteforce it and check all 120 permutations in $S_5$?

Comment: $(4\, 5)$ will also commute with it. Hence the sub group generated by $\{(1 \,2\, 3), (4\,5)\}$ will be the normalizer.

Comment: @Muralidharan so far I have $\{e, (\begin{smallmatrix}1 & 2 & 3\end{smallmatrix}), (\begin{smallmatrix}1 & 3 & 2\end{smallmatrix}), (\begin{smallmatrix}4 & 5\end{smallmatrix})\}$, would there be any more?

Comment: $(123)(45), (132)(45)$

Comment: $N$ usually stands for normaliser (of a subgroup). This is not the same as the centraliser. For example, $(12)$ normalises the subgroup generated by $(123)$, even though it does not commute with $(123)$.

Comment: @verret I know this, but when you're trying to get the normalizer with one element, isn't it basically the same thing as the centralizer? Since the definition of $N_G(S)=\{g\in G|gS=Sg\}$, and when S has one element, it turns into the centralizer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $H=N_{S_5}(\{(123)\})$. We know that $(123)$ normalizes itself, so $(123)\in H$. On the other hand,$(45)\in H$, because $(123)$ and $(45)$ are disjoint.

Suppose that $\sigma\in H\setminus\left<(123),(45)\right>$ (that is set subtraction, not a quotient). If $\sigma i\in\{4,5\}$ for some $i\in\{1,2,3\}$, then $\sigma(123)\sigma^{-1}$ cannot be equal to $(123)$. This is because conjugation by $\sigma$ would replace $i$ by $j$ in the 3-cycle. Therefore, the set $\{4,5\}$ is stable under $\sigma$. Multiplying $\sigma$ by $(45)$ if necessary, we may assume that $\sigma$ fixes 4 and 5.

So $\sigma$ is a permutation of $1,2,3$. Since we assumed that $\sigma\notin\left<(123)\right>$, we must have that $\sigma$ is a transposition. But $\sigma(123)\sigma^{-1}=(132)$ for all transpositions in $S_3$. This contradiction implies that there is no such $\sigma$ to begin with. In particular, $H=\left<(123),(45)\right>.$