# Normalizer of $(1 2 3 4 5)$ in $S_5$

Tags: group-theory

Finding two elements in $A_5$ which are conjugate in $S_5$ but not in $A_5$.

I've proved that if $a$ & $b$ are conjugate in $S_5$ but not in $A_5$ then all elements in the normalizer $N(a)$ must be even permutations. ([link to the proof.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-5MmZFc0R5_NgrHujvnnXUzYO6WLQao5/view?usp=drivesdk))

All elements in $A_5$ are of the form $(1 2 3 4 5)$ or $(1 2 3)$ or $(1 2)(3 4)$.

From here,  [Finding the normalizer of a group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1988627/finding-the-normalizer-of-a-group)    ,$(1 2 3)$ is ruled out because its normalizer contains $(4 5)$, an odd element.

I think Normalizer of $(1 2 3 4 5)$ contains $e$ and $(1 2 3 4 5)$ only, because none of 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 is stable under this permutation. Please help me decide if all elements in normalizer of $(1 2 3 4 5)$ are indeed even.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: The normalizer (or as most people would say centralizer) of an element is a subgroup, so in your case will contain at least the five powers of $(12345)$ and not just have two elements as you say. Your reason isn't good enough even once you've corrected this - for instance in $S_6$ none of 1,2,3,4,5,6 is stable under $(123)(456)$ but the centraliser contains things like $(14)(25)(36)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normaliser of a single element is the same as the elements that commute with it, that is, it is the centraliser.

Clearly, the entire cyclic group $\langle (12345)\rangle $ satisfies the condition.

By the orbit-stabilizer theorem,  this is the entire centraliser.

( That is, there is a theorem that if you consider the action of conjugation, then cycle structure is preserved.   Furthermore,  any two permutations of the same cycle type are conjugate.  Thus the theorem says that the orbit of the conjugation action consists of all $24$ five-cycles.

Now we get $\mid C(12345)\mid=\mid S_5\mid/{24}=120/{24}=5$, where $C(12345)$ is the centraliser.)

Answer (score 1):

Since $(12345)$ is a single element, its normaliser is its centraliser.

**Hint:** Consider, for $\alpha\in S_5$, the elements of the form $$\alpha^{-1}(12345)\alpha.$$

Comment: My somewhat educated guess would be that the question really is about the normalizer of the cyclic subgroup $\langle(12345)\rangle$. At least I have never heard of the normalizer of a set other than a subgroup.

Comment: Hmm. Reading the rest of the question makes me doubt my guess :-)